# Java comparing enumerator (Strange behaviour)

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I work with a Java project and Eclipse(Version 3.6.2) as IDE, in a enum comparison i get a strange behaviour, following an example of the weirdness :

Global Variable :

```
StatusType status = StatusType.SIGNATURE;
```

Code :

```
                String trsStatus = "END";
            if(trsStatus.equals("END") && (this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0)){
                //Do something
                }
```

This comparison succeeds and enter in the if block, Why ? In this case the second evaluation(this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0) of the if statements fail because the result is false ! Why java however enter in the block ???

If i evaluate the expression on the expression watcher of eclipse debugger the value of the statements are :

> trsStatus.equals("END")                            ---> true
>
> (this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0) ---> false

I've done another test, if i assign the result of the second expression in the if statements to a boolean variable :

```
boolean sign = (this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0);
```

i get this result :

> (this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0) ---> false
>
> sign                                               ---> true

Why ?!?

How this can be possible ?

Comment: Are you really sure you are entering the `if` block?  You could also define a `boolean` as the whole expression, including the `&&`, and check that it is false.

Comment: Yes enter in the if block, is incredible ... I've also tried to define a boolean variable that include the two expression but the problem remain the same .

Comment: What's the value of that var? false?

Comment: How do you know it enters the `if`?

Comment: You must be victim of the silliest of all mistakes. Because this can't be. Sleep over it :)

Comment: The value of the var was false, i know that enter in the if block because the debugger enter in it. The only way for workaround this situation i by doing this : boolean sign = (this.status.name().equals(StatusType.SIGNATURE.name()));

Comment: So you claim `boolean bool = false; if (bool) { // does enter }`?  You are misusing your debugger.  Try debugging by hand: put a `System.out.println("reached inside if");` within your `if` block.  It will not print out with a `if (false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Could it be that `StatusType` overrides `compareTo()` in some weird way?</s>

Are there any other threads that could be changing the value of the `status` field?

In any case, you should use `equals()` or even `==` rather than `compareTo()` here.

Answer (score 2):

`this.status.compareTo(StatusType.SIGNATURE) != 0` will return zero, because zero means they are equal. `compareTo()` returns either 1, -1, or 0, based on which value is considered greater.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible reason I could imagine is that

```
this.status != StatusType.SIGNATURE
```

Period. You probably set status to some other value unknowingly. Maybe with another thread. Who knows. What does status evaluate to, in your debugger?

In any case, there is certainly no such "bug" in Java. Unless you post some more code that proves it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `this.status != StatusType.SIGNATURE`.

Comment: Also with this expression i get the same undesired result .

Comment: Use a Debugger to see what the value of this.status is when you get to the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEnum e = TestEnum.SIGNATURE;
        System.out.println(e.compareTo(TestEnum.SIGNATURE));
        String test = "test";
        if (test.equals("test") && e.compareTo(TestEnum.SIGNATURE) != 0) {
            System.out.println("I'm here");
        }
    }
}
```

I did the following test. It does not enter the if block and print "I'm here".

Can you post your snippet?